# return total on python

Tags: python

im having trouble with modular python on returning the total and then printing it in the output. lend a hand?

```
def main():
    Monday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Monday: "))
    Tuesday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Tuesday: "))
    Wednesday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Wednesday: "))
    Thursday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Thursday: "))
    Friday = int(input("Enter the store sales or Friday: "))

    total = totalSales()
    print("the total sales for the week are:", total)


def totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday):
    weeklyTotal = Monday + Tuesday + Wednesday + Thursday + Friday
    return weeklyTotal

main()
```

Error message:

```
Enter the store sales for Monday: 5
Enter the store sales for Tuesday: 4
Enter the store sales for Wednesday: 6
Enter the store sales for Thursday: 2
Enter the store sales or Friday: 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "so.py", line 8, in main
    total = totalSales()
TypeError: totalSales() takes exactly 5 arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: Maybe if you stated the nature of your "trouble", someone could help you.

Comment: You haven't specified what your problem is. But I'm willing to bet that the main problem you are facing is that you are not passing the required arguments to `totalSales()`. Look at how you defined the function, and look at how you are calling it.

Comment: im trying to add up all the total of sales in the in totalsales and then returning it

Comment: @vtecjustkickedinyo You still haven't explained what your *problem* is. Also, did you read my comment? Read your code very carefully. You have to pass the arguments to the function you are calling.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: `def totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday):` has 5 arguments that being `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday`, and `Friday` but when you do `total = totalSales()` you have nothing in those parentheses - Your arguments go there! To fix just have function call to look like `total = totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the required information to your function.  You have five input parameters.  When you call the function, you have to give it five values.

```
total = totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)
```

... in your **main** should fix the problem.

---

**DETAIL**

The problem I see when I run your code looks like this.
Notice the last line of the error message: it describes the problem.
In the future, remember to include this in your posting.

```
Enter the store sales for Monday: 5
Enter the store sales for Tuesday: 4
Enter the store sales for Wednesday: 6
Enter the store sales for Thursday: 2
Enter the store sales or Friday: 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "so.py", line 8, in main
    total = totalSales()
TypeError: totalSales() takes exactly 5 arguments (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments to the totalSales function.
When you call a function with arguments, remember to include them in the call. As a very basic example:

**Function**

```
def AddNumbers(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**Call**

```
AddNumbers(1,2) #<-1 and 2 represent x and y in the above function
```

In your code you have the function declared as:

```
def totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday):
```

But when you call it you don't pass any of the arguments:

```
total = totalSales()
```

It should be:

```
def main():
    Monday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Monday: "))
    Tuesday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Tuesday: "))
    Wednesday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Wednesday: "))
    Thursday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Thursday: "))
    Friday = int(input("Enter the store sales or Friday: "))

    total = totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)
    print("the total sales for the week are:", total)


def totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday):
    weeklyTotal = Monday + Tuesday + Wednesday + Thursday + Friday
    return weeklyTotal

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the required arguments to your `totalSales()` function as it takes 5 arguments and you are not giving any. I have also fixed you print statement as the output looked weird.

The code:

```
def main():
    Monday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Monday: "))
    Tuesday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Tuesday: "))
    Wednesday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Wednesday: "))
    Thursday = int(input("Enter the store sales for Thursday: "))
    Friday = int(input("Enter the store sales or Friday: "))

    total = totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) # Added arguments to function
    print("the total sales for the week are: %s" % total) # Fixed Print


def totalSales(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday):
    weeklyTotal = Monday + Tuesday + Wednesday + Thursday + Friday
    return weeklyTotal

main()
```